Why am I able to navigate directly to Okta's SSO login URL without sending a SAML request from the Service Provider?
I'm working with SAML authentication using an SP-initiated flow, where my Service Provider (SP) should generate a SAML request, which is sent to the Identity Provider (IdP) to start the login process.
However, I noticed that I can manually navigate directly to the Okta SSO login URL (IdP endpoint) without the SP sending the SAML request. This seems to bypass the typical SAML flow where the request is essential for initiating the authentication and ensuring it's coming from the SP. I thought the whole point of SAML authentication is that it verifies the request and response? But this flow  seems to contradict the entire thing, or am I not understanding something correctly?

Unclear what endpoint you're trying but Identity Provider initiated flow is a valid flow. See Plan for SAML section in https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/saml/
